# Can anyone identify this Autogyro?

Tags: aircraft-identification, rotorcraft, autogyro

I've found similar autogyros on the internet, but not this one. Most autogyros appear to have 2 cockpits and this autogyro only has one.  Although I have matched its angle-tipped wings with other autogyros, I cannot match the configuration of the landing gear.  It appears that each wheel has a vertical strut to the wing and then two bars in a triangular configuration that attach to a center bar about 12" below the fuselage. The only autogyro I've found that appears to possibly be the same is in this video, but the craft's make and model not identified.

The video is from California but I'm assuming my photo was taken in Wisconsin. I sincerely appreciate your assistance.[image]

Comment: You're taking it to the next level :-)

Answer (score 6):

It looks like a Kellet K-3, I believe...

Photo from 'Cierva Autogiros', by Peter Brooks.

[image]

Comment: You may have identified it. The main reason I concur is the landing gear.  Your photo is the ONLY one I've seen with the same landing gear configuration.  The rest appears to be a match although I'm not quite sure about the verticle stabilizer, rudder, and elevators.  They are difficult to see in my photo but appear to be more rounded. I also cannot discern a windscreen in my photo. Perhaps a slightly different model? I found this K-3 video, but it has an enclosed cockpit and the same tail configuration as your photo.  https://youtu.be/AUVwHGpoasM   Thank you!

Comment: I think it is a Kellet K-2 or K-2A. The K-3 had a [5 cylinder engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinner_C-5), the K-2/2A were fitted with a [7 cylinder engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continental_R-670). The aircraft in the question seems to have a 7 cylinder version.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to call it and move on even though I'm still in a quandry about the elevators appearing to be round and all other photos I come across show them to be straight across at a bit of an angle.  But the rotor mast and landing gear are only matching a Kellet Autogiro.  Here is a photo that I feel most closely matches.  Unfortunately it doesn't give a model designation, but I'll go with the K-2 version due to engine and the fact that there seems to be very few K-2 photos on the internet.  https://www.flickr.com/photos/boston_public_library/5934695886/in/photostream/

Comment: I thank all contributors for their help. All answers led me to this conclusion.  Very much appreciated.